# Type Error: Init Requires 1 Positional Argument Yet 2 Are Given

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, forms, django-views

Hey so I'm getting this error when I'm trying to make a text area on my site to update a user's 'about' information. It just handles the info of an existing user to update their 'about' field. Any more info needed just let me know and any insight/solutions would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

```
class change_about(UpdateView):
 def get_object(self, queryset=None):

     return User.objects.get(user=self.request.user)

 def form_valid(self, form):

     instance = form.instance # This is the new object being saved
     instance.user = self.request.user
     instance.save()

     return super(change_about, self).form_valid(form)
```

AbstractUser:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    is_moderator = models.BooleanField(default = False)
    about = models.TextField(blank = True, null = True)
    notifications = models.ManyToManyField(Notification, related_name = 
    'notifications_user', blank = True)
```

Comment: Could you post the whole error? The error in the title doesn't tell us WHAT is causing the type error.

Answer (score 0):

You need use [as_view()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/class-based-views/base/#django.views.generic.base.View.as_view) at the end of class based views when declaring in the urls:

```
path('change_about/', views.change_about.as_view(), name='change_about')
```

Comment: This worked for that error. Now it is: Cannot resolve keyword 'user' into field. Choices are: about, comment, date_joined, email, first_name, from_user, groups, id, is_active, is_moderator, is_staff, is_superuser, last_login, last_name, logentry, notifications, password, stories_user, story, user_permissions, username

Comment: On this line:  return User.objects.get(user=self.request.user)

Comment: This would be like that.
User.objects.get(id=self.request.user.id)

Comment: Because User model has no 'user' field.

Comment: I have an AbstractUser extending auth.User with their own custom fields too, is there a good way to go about updating the 'about' field extended within AbstractUser?

Comment: Please share your custom user model code here.

Comment: Updated in original post

Comment: You can add custom field to user creation form to save data.

class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('email', 'about')

Comment: I have one for about already, which is all I need to edit, inside UserChangeForm I think

Comment: You need this one. @JohnDOe

class CustomUserChangeForm(UserChangeForm):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('email', 'about')

Comment: then change any more of my codde or all ok?

Comment: fields = ('email', 'about')

Comment: Just add fields value. Whatever field you want to update.

Comment: After changing all that, I get this : Using ModelFormMixin (base class of change_about) without the 'fields' attribute is prohibited.